# Why Scapy can't forge IP src in python?

Tags: python, sockets, security, networking, scapy

I have python3, scapy 2.4.4 installed on my local machine.
I want to send an ICMP packet from my local network to a server in another country, basically out of my private network.
I execute this line when i use scapy :

> pkt = IP(dst="server IP ADDRESS")/ICMP()/"from
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

Then i execute it

> send(pkt)

On the server side, which is outside of my home network (somewhere outside of the country), i receive the ping request  which shows my home network public IP address.

but if i want to set the src to something outside of my home private network, for instance, 212.145.15.17 or anything else , it doesn't work. On the server side, still my public IP address will be shown in the ICMP packet.

> pkt = IP(src="an IP outside of my private network",dst="server IP ADDRESS")/ICMP()/"from
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

I tried with the TCP and UDP packets. Forging the source IP address doesn't work!!! i'm wondering whether it works only in the private network or not?

I appreciate your assistance. I searched a lot and didn't find anything.

Comment: That is because your NAT (Network Address Translation) router is performing network address translation, replacing the source IP address with its outside IP address.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for your response. is there ( like a dedicated server) any sort of network where there would be no NAT in front of my network?

Comment: You do not seem to have a programming problem, and are now asking about a network question. Unfortunately, product or resource recommendation are off-topic on almost all SE sites. You could always get a VPC with one of the cloud providers.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this issue that the code for sure works but it is a networking issue. Thats a good idea VPC. Thankssss.